# responsive toggle navbar - using css only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive toggle menu with css only and below is the code. Any kind of help will be appreciable. No javascript or jquery - only css. Below is the code snippet hope with css and html -it is clear.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container{
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.p-t {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.p-t .p-to {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.p-header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
  background-color:#c6c6c6;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.list-inline > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
.p-header .list-inline li a{
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 line-height: 80px;
}
.p-header .list-inline li.active a,
.p-header .list-inline li a:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-header">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="p-t">
  <div class="p-to"><a><img src="white.png"></a></div>
   <div class="p-to text-right">
    <ul class="list-inline header-menu">
     <li><a>Home</a></li>
     <li><a>BUsiness</a></li>
     <li><a>About</a></li>
     <li><a>Login</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need more information. What do you mean by responsive? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @Ethilium means only for small screen navbar should be toggable

Comment: You also mention CSS only, but you have JS listed as a tag. Do you want a CSS only solution or one with JS as well?

Comment: @Ethilium css is priority but in case its not a solution then last option JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly toggling is impossible without a little bit of javascript.
I suggest you give `a` an id. What ever you want to show/hide give it an id, for example `navbar`

```
<a id="nav-toggle" style="display: none"><img src="white.png"></a>
<div id="navbar">navbar ul goes in here</div>
```

To automatically hide the navbar up to a certain display width or height use a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #nav-toggle {
        display: inline;
    }
    #navbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You can do JS something like this:

```
var toggler = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
toggler.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(navbar.style.display === 'none') {
        navbar.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        navbar.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaq2d5jr/)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get your question.
But I'll assume. I did the following using an input as a checkbox with a label.
The checkbox has flag checking as true and false.
When it is checked it sends a true pointing at the mobile class menu to display:block. I used opacity on the checkbox to "hide it" so when you click the hamburger icon you're clicking the checkbox. (Resize to 700px, for hamburger icon)
Here is what I did. Excuse my writing and English.

```js
// This JS is use to change between the hamburger icon and the X icon
checkbox = document.getElementById("hamburger");
lab = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

function checker(){
 if(checkbox.checked == false){
   lab[0].innerHTML = '☰';
  }else{
   lab[0].innerHTML = '✖';
  }
}

checkbox.onclick = function(){
 checker();
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
.container{
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.list-inline{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}
.list-inline li a{
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.list-inline li a:hover{
  color: #ff0f00;
}

#hamburger{
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:15px;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid #555;
}

label{
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.mobile{
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-300px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00a86b;
}

.mobile li{
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.mobile-menu{
  display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  label{
    display:block;
    z-index:4;
  }
  .list-inline{
    display:none;
  }
  .mobile{
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .mobile-menu{display: block;}
  .mobile li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .mobile li a:hover{
    color: red;
  }
  #hamburger{cursor: pointer;}
  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul.mobile{
  transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <input id="hamburger" type="checkbox" name="hamb" value="hamb">
      <label for="hamb">☰</label>
      <ul class="mobile">
     <li><a>Home</a></li>
     <li><a>Business</a></li>
     <li><a>About</a></li>
     <li><a>Login</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  <ul class="list-inline header-menu">
   <li><a>Home</a></li>
   <li><a>Business</a></li>
   <li><a>About</a></li>
   <li><a>Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g64cqjx5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

One way to make CSS for smaller screens is doing media queries.

```
@media (max-width:768px){
   . your-class{
      your-attribute: your-value;
   }
}
```

Thus, when a screen below 768px is browsing your page it will take those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an hack with an invisible checkbox behind the option you want to toogle, something like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(lightblue), to(lightgreen));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, lightblue, lightgreen);
}

.nav .main_item {
  position: relative;
}

.nav .main_item h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav .main_item h3::after {
  content: "\25B8";
}

.nav .main_item .flow-control:checked + h3::after {
  content: "\25BE";
}

.nav .main_item .flow-control {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav .main_item .flow-control:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav .main_item ul {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: none;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
  <ul class="nav">
        <li class="main_item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="flow-control">
            <h3>Main Item 1</h3>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 1</li>
                <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 2</li>
                <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main_item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="flow-control">
            <h3>Main Item 2</h3>
            <ul>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 1</li>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 2</li>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="main_item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="flow-control">
            <h3>Main Item 3</h3>
            <ul>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 1</li>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 2</li>
                    <li class="sub_item">Sub-item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```